# How do I use regex to get the key information from a string in Python?

Tags: python

I have a string where I want to extract the key information from:

```
gbk_kings_common_20171201_20180131_66000.0k_2017-12-01_TO_2018-01-31_id12_1277904128.csv
```

Namely, I would like to find the following:

1. File identifier, e.g. `gbk_kings_common_20171201_20180131`
2. Size, e.g. `330.0k`
3. Date, e.g. `2017-12-01_TO_2018-02-31`
4. Type of id, e.g. `id12_12771231518`

But I'm having a difficulty compiling the regex since the file identifier can always change in the length, although the rest of the information is pretty fixed when delimited by commas.

Comment: have you written any code for this already?

Comment: Do you have any control on the string? In such case, it is much easier if you change the character separating the different parts, since having `_` both inside the identifier and between different parts of the string makes it much more difficult.

Comment: Could you specify how the file identifier varies? Does it simply add more dates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the pattern `r'(.*)_(.*)_([\d-]+_TO_[\d-]+)_(id[\d_]*)` to search your string.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "gbk_kings_common_20171201_20180131_66000.0k_2017-12-01_TO_2018-01-31_id12_1277904128.csv"
>>> sre = re.search(r'(.*)_(.*)_([\d-]+_TO_[\d-]+)_(id[\d_]*)', s)
>>> file_id, size, date, type_id = sre.groups()
>>> print (file_id, size, date, type_id)
gbk_kings_common_20171201_20180131 66000.0k 2017-12-01_TO_2018-01-31 id12_1277904128
```

Comment: I can see that `gbk_kings_common_20171201_20180131_66000.0k_` refers to the groups `(.*)_(.*)` but how do you know that the second `(.*)` refer to `66000.0k` and not something like `20171201_20180131_66000.0k`?

Comment: @winnie99. If it matches `20171201_20180131`, then the next pattern `([\d-]+_TO_[\d-]+)` wouldn't match. So the first `(.*)`, would match everything upto the last but one `_` before the dates